# Does my network really have two paths?

Tags: machine-learning, keras, conv-neural-network

I would like to compare two images of similar nature with Keras model. So, I was thinking to build something like this

[image]

Simultaneously, I though to share convolutional weights in both branches, so I wrote

```
    input1 = Input((resample_size[0], resample_size[1], image_channels))
    input2 = Input((resample_size[0], resample_size[1], image_channels))

    # VGG-like layer sequence
    conv_layers = [
        Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu'),
        Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu'),
        MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2, 2)),
        Dropout(0.25),

        ...

    ]

    prev = input1
    for layer in conv_layers:
        prev = layer(prev)

    out1 = prev

    prev = input2
    for layer in conv_layers:
        prev = layer(prev)

    out2 = prev

    final_layers = [
        Flatten(),

        Dense(512, activation='relu'),
        ...
    ]

    concat = Concatenate()
    prev = concat([out1, out2])
    ...
```

I was thinking that this will give me two branches which will learn same features and that they will be compared at the end.

Unfortunately, Keras plotting thing draws me

[image]

I.e. it is not evident, that my network has two branched.

The question is: does my network really have two braches? Or the structure is somehow broken?

Comment: and where is the concat in thi image?

Comment: It is below. It is just another rectangle.